# Need help making sense of these for loop outputs

Tags: c

```
int i, a[7] = {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6};
for (i = 0; i < 4 || a[i]; i++)
    putchar('*');
```

This loop doesn't make sense to me because it prints out 8 *'s. It's for C.

So from what I understand:

- `0 < 4 || -6` ⟶ `*`
- `1 < 4 || -4` ⟶ `*`
- `2 < 4 || -2` ⟶ `*`
- `3 < 4 || 0` ⟶ `*`
- `4 < 4 || 2` ⟶ `*`
- `5 < 4 || 4` ⟶ `*`
- `6 < 4 || 6` ⟶ `*`

So that's 7 stars so far...After this is it doing

- `7 < 4 || '\0'` ⟶ `*`

This is a similar question that prints out 5 stars:

```
int i, a[2] = {-6, -4};
for (i = 0; i < 4 || a[i]; i++)
    putchar('*');
```

Again I don't understand what it's doing on the last time around.

When it gets to `4 < 4 || ?`, shouldn't it break?

Answer (score 2):

This code has undefined behavior because it will access elements outside the array.  You can see this behavior if you change your code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i, a[7] = {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6};
  for (i = 0; i < 4 || a[i]; i++) {
    printf("Accessing element: %d\n", i);
    putchar('*');
  }
}
```

On my machine I get the following output:

```
Accessing element: 0
*Accessing element: 1
*Accessing element: 2
*Accessing element: 3
*Accessing element: 4
*Accessing element: 5
*Accessing element: 6
*Accessing element: 7
*Accessing element: 8
*
```

This is accessing 9 elements (index 8 is element 9 of a zero based index array).  Once you have undefined behavior all bets are basically off.  It is also possible that the program will loop until it reaches a segmentation fault.

It doesn't break when `i == 4` or when `i` is greater than 4 because `a[i]` is true and therefore `i < 4 || a[i]` is also true.  `a[i]` is true up to the array length and then you access something outside the array (the 8th element, index 7) and then you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the loop condition is bogus and leads to accessing the array beyond its bounds.

Remember there's no bounds check on arrays done by the language or any implicit *null* at the end of array in C. A lot of invalid code compiles just fine. It's your responsibility as a programmer to ensure your code is valid.

A correct loop condition would ensure the array is not accessed outside it's boundary:

```
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof a/sizeof a[0]) && a[i]; i++)
    putchar('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

An integer is considered "true" if it is nonzero. All the cases in your first example where it gets as far as looking at a[I] have that value nonzero, and anything ored with true is true.

(@CyberSpock spells this out in more detail)

Comment: This answer misses the key point, that the code (both sample loops in the question) has undefined behaviour because it accesses outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Jonathanleffler:Also true, and a bigger problem, granted.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, a[7] = {-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6};
for (i = 0; i < 4 || a[i]; i++)
```

If you look at the condition

```
i < 4 || a[i]
```

It means that the expression is true if *either* `i` is less than 4 i.e. elements at [0-3] of the array will be true **OR** if `a[i]` is not 0 (`a[i]` is the short form for `a[i] != 0`)

The array has an element that is zero, it is at a[3] but will anyway be printed because the other part of the or condition is true for that position: `i < 4`

When dealing with arrays like this it is good to know the size of the array and have that as the max value even if you want to break on a particular value.

```
int N=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

or

```
#define N 7

for (i = 0; i < N && a[i]; i++)
```

this will prevent you from reading random values from the stack (in this case).